# Css background image not showing up (GitHub Pages)

Tags: html, css

`background-image: url("../images/digital-marketing-meeting.jpg");`

I know it's how I have my files rooted and/or how I'm linking the image in my css but I cannot figure out why the image wont load.

GitHub repo: https://github.com/DylanSchmidt2/Challenge-repo-1

Comment: from what I can tell it's not about the image url but the div it's-self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a try like this:

```css
    background-image: url("/images/digital-marketing-meeting.jpg");
```

on my environment that works fine

Answer (score 0):

The background image url in your [css file](https://github.com/DylanSchmidt2/Challenge-repo-1/blob/main/css/style.css#L65) is wrong.

Current :

```css
background-image: url("../css/digital-marketing-meeting.jpg");
```

Correct :

```css
background-image: url("images/digital-marketing-meeting.jpg");
```